# Ionic 2: Cannot find name ‘Promise’ after updating to RC.0

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, ionic2, visual-studio-code

I have just updated my Ionic 2 project to RC.0 and now have several typescript errors that I think are all related:

- Cannot find Promise
- Property 'find' does not exist on array (paraphrased as happens with any types of array).

**Q) How can I fix this, so that my code will compile?**

I'm using Visual Studio Code btw.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "updating to RC.0". RC.0 is quite old. Why don't you update to final?

Comment: Ionic 2: RC 0 september 28th!

Comment: sounds like the infamous typings issues. make sure your typings are up to date and run an npm install. Also you want to make sure VS is up to date as well, they recently updated their plug-in.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed Angular2 RC.0.

Comment: @Bean0341: Can you provide an answer please?  I don't want to mess up all the other npm dependencies and versions in the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gave up and reinstalled Visual Studio Code, fixed.

Then followed these steps:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript#_using-newer-typescript-versions

What fun!

Comment: damn just posted answer LOL

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making sure your typescript is all up to date. In your package.json make sure you have the most recent approve typescript update, should be :

`"typescript": "2.0.3"`

since you are already in you package.json take the time to make sure all other dependencies are up to date as well. cross reference with the angular.io docs to make sure.

Run an NPM install

you also want to make sure VS is up to date you can download it from Microsoft [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593), you will need to restart VS as well once the install is complete.

Comment: I spoke too soon, errors back, and I followed exactly what you said here.